# Metric on $\mathbb{R}$ that agrees with the topology and closure condition

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ be the real line with the usual Euclidean metric
$$d(a,b)=|a-b|.$$
Can one construct a new metric $d'$ such that $d'$ induces the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as $d$ and $d'$ satisfies
$$d'(A,B)=0 \iff \bar{A}\cap\bar{B}\neq \emptyset,$$
for all $A,B \subseteq X,$ where
$$d'(A,B)=\inf \{d'(a,b) \mid a\in A, b \in B\}?$$
Clearly the original metric $d$ does not satisfy that condition: take $A=\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $B=\{n-\frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want the same topology, we have $\lim_{k=1}^\infty n+\frac 1k=n$, hence for each $n\in\Bbb N$, we find $b_n$ with $n<b_n<n+\frac1n$ and $d'(b_n,n)<\frac 1n$. Then replacing your $B$ with $B':=\{\,b_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$, we have $\bar A\cap \bar B'=\emptyset$ and $d'(A,B')=0$.

Comment: How exactly did you define your $d'?$

Comment: @Pawel He is proving that such a  metric $d'$ does not exist. Nice proof, in fact.

Comment: @Pawel. Let $d'$ be any equivalent to $d$ (i.e. generates the same topology). Each $n\in \Bbb N$ is in the closure of $(n,n+1/n)$ so there exists $b_n\in (n,n+1/n)$ with $d'(n,b_n)<1/n.$ This implies $\bar A\cap \bar B'=\phi$ and $d'(A,B')=0$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!